# Div being resized when site accessed remotely

Tags: php, html, apache

This is a strange question and to be honest I have no idea what to provide to help you answer this. I have a website locally set up on my Ubuntu computer. I am able to access it remotely with any other device on the network, only one thing: The navigation bar is about two times taller than it is when accessed on the local computer. Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it? I have error reporting on and there are no errors to be seen.

Comment: use websafe fonts,

Comment: Turned out it was the font. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a link to a CSS file is only being accessed locally.

Kev